# Proguard Capabilities and Configuration

Tags: android, android-proguard

I have some questions about Proguard configuration:

1. Why Proguard doesn't obfuscate my class with these code?

**Java**

```
public static String encrypt(String keyString, String text) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(...);

        ...

        byte[] key = new byte[...];
        ...
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ...);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(...));

        return ...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

**Proguard**

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {public static <fields>;}
-keep class **.R$*
-keepattributes JavaScriptInterface

# If you want to enable optimization, you should include the
# following:
# -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
# -optimizationpasses 5
# -allowaccessmodification
#
# Note that you cannot just include these flags in your own
# configuration file; if you are including this file, optimization
# will be turned off. You'll need to either edit this file, or
# duplicate the contents of this file and remove the include of this
# file from your project's proguard.config path property.

-keepattributes *Annotation*

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
# -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
#    native <methods>;
# }

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int d(...);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembernames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

What could be wrong to prevent my code to be obfuscated?

2. What I learn is, do not obfuscate **Activity** and **Fragment** using Proguard, am I right?
3. Proguard does not able to obfuscate `strings.xml` and instead replace the strings to the Java code?

Answer (score 0):

You should have added the default proguard config file `proguard-android.txt` provide by Android SDK.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

---

> What I learn is, do not obfuscate Activity and Fragment using Proguard, am I right?

YES, those Activities and Fragment classes should be preserved (using `-keep`) as the entry points for Proguard.

---

> Proguard does not able to obfuscate strings.xml and instead replace the strings to the Java code?

Yes, Proguard only does resource shrinking but not resource obfuscation according to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code,

> Resource shrinking is available with the Android plugin for Gradle,
>   which removes unused resources from your packaged app, including
>   unused resources in code libraries. It works in conjunction with code
>   shrinking such that once unused code has been removed, any resources
>   no longer referenced can be safely removed as well.

Check more details from android SDK directory: `<your-path>/sdk/tools/proguard`

Comment: the code is still readable even though I use `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')`, and it's also deprecated for Gradle 2.2+: `This file is no longer maintained and is not used by new (2.2+) versions of the Android plugin for Gradle. Instead, the Android plugin for Gradle generates the default rules at build time and stores them in the build directory.`